# iOS-Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data'

Tags: ios, json, swift4

I have a JSON data as a string and i want to decode this data to a list of object but im getting this error: "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data'"

this is my code:

```
struct DatabaseObject: Decodable{
    var CityNameL = ""
    var DBName = ""
    var DBNameID = 0
    var IDName = ""
}

func jsonToObject(json:String){


    do{
     let databases = try  JSONDecoder().decode(DatabaseObject.self,from: json)
    }catch let jsonErr {
     print(jsonErr)
    }
 }
```

this is the json data:

```
[{"CityNameL":"Skeleton East","DBName":"SkeletonEAST","DBNameID":29,"IDName":"SKELETONEASTLOCAL"},{"CityNameL":"SKELETON DEMO/SKELETON DEMO","DBName":"SKELETONDEMO","DBNameID":30,"IDName":"SKELETONEASTDOT2"},{"CityNameL":"SKELETONPARAMS","DBName":"FFMSCENTRAL","DBNameID":31,"IDName":"FFMSCENTRALLOCAL"},{"CityNameL":"SKELECBM","DBName":"SKELETONFFMS","DBNameID":32,"IDName":"LOCAL"}]
```

so is there a way to convert String to Data or is there other way for decoding it.

Comment: `JSONDecoder().decode(DatabaseObject.self,from: json)` The `from` params needs to be a `Data` object, not a `String` one. Either you did have before hand a `Data` and, and pass it, or you do `JSONDecoder().decode(DatabaseObject.self, from: json.data(encoding: .utf8))`

Comment: i tried json.data(encoding: .utf8)) but i got this error: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: The debugDescription tells you exactly what’s wrong. *Expected* is what you do and *found* is what it actually is.

Comment: `JSONDecoder().decode([DatabaseObject].self,from: json.data(encoding: .utf8))`, but that's a wild guess because you don't want to show us the JSON.

Comment: yes, i know but I'm new to iOS and i don't know what exactly the solution

Comment: It’s very simple. There are only two collection types: Dictionary which is the destination struct and Array which is an array of the destination struct and the compiler says it’s **not** dictionary.

Comment: i updated my question with JSON data

Comment: Larme gave you the proper solution a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try This to convert your `String` json to `Data`

```
import Foundation

struct DatabaseObject: Decodable{
    var CityNameL : String
    var DBName  : String
    var DBNameID  : Int
    var IDName  : String
}


func jsonToObject(json:Data){
    do{
       // let somedata = Data(json.utf8)
       let databases = try  JSONDecoder().decode([DatabaseObject].self,from: json)
       print(databases)
    }catch let jsonErr {
     print(jsonErr)
    }
 }

let json = """
[{"CityNameL":"Skeleton East","DBName":"SkeletonEAST","DBNameID":29,"IDName":"SKELETONEASTLOCAL"},{"CityNameL":"SKELETON DEMO","DBName":"SKELETONDEMO","DBNameID":30,"IDName":"SKELETONEASTDOT2"},{"CityNameL":"SKELETONPARAMS","DBName":"FFMSCENTRAL","DBNameID":31,"IDName":"FFMSCENTRALLOCAL"},{"CityNameL":"SKELECBM","DBName":"SKELETONFFMS","DBNameID":32,"IDName":"LOCAL"}]
""".data(using: .utf8)! 
// our data in native (JSON) format
jsonToObject(json:json)
```

Comment: Better `let somedata = Data(json.utf8)`. Converting from an utf8 string can never fail.

Comment: So let databases = try  JSONDecoder().decode(DatabaseObject.self,from: Data(json.utf8)) . @vadian (Y)

Comment: Yes, but `DatabaseObject` is supposed to be an array.

Comment: i still getting this catch error: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: @aoemail Sadly it will. You just need to mapped that json data to your DatabaseObject right ?

Comment: @aoemail Once again: Please read the comments (and learn to read JSON). The second comment of Larme gave you the solution : It's `JSONDecoder().decode([DatabaseObject].self ...`. Note the **brackets** which represent an array in Swift and in JSON.

Comment: @aoemail now you will get all arrays as object. Check answer again. Please up vote and mark as answer. thnx